# Replace data set every min

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to have my Highstock chart update every minute, by replacing its existing data set with one that is extracted from a url request (which would have different data at different times).

So far I'm not even able to get the data to refresh based on manual changes.

Work so far: https://jsfiddle.net/Lz8gLw8j/

I'm trying to test changing data and then updating it with:

```
varData = [[0,0],[1,2]]
$('#chart2').highcharts().redraw();
```

Which does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the new data to highchart in following way:

```
     var newData = [
       [1251763200000, 23.61],
       [1251849600000, 23.60],
       [1251936000000, 23.79]
     ]

     var chart = $('#chart2').highcharts();
     chart.series[0].setData(newData);

     $('#chart2').highcharts().redraw();
```

Updated fiddler:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lz8gLw8j/5/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a load event that you can use

```
chart : {
    events : {
        load : function () {

            // set up the updating of the chart each second
            var series = this.series[0];
            setInterval(function () {
                var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jjwilly16/Lz8gLw8j/6/

FYI: I pulled this from an example off of the Highcharts website: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/

Answer (score 0):

You can add data to the existing series using the `addPoint` method and replace the dataset using the `setData` method. The second option argument for both of the methods allows you to redraw the chart. The data should be an array of arrays. The nested array contains the actual data that is plotted. The first elements of the inner, nested array is the epoch (x) while the second is the actual value (y). The epoch is the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 Midnight GMT/UTC. I have updated the fiddle to allow you to add data points as well as reset the data.

The main change are these lines:

```
$('#updateButton').click(function() {
   var date = $('#newDate').val();
   var epoch = Math.round(new Date(date).getTime());
   var value = parseInt($('#newValue').val());
   var chart = $('#chart2').highcharts();
   chart.series[0].addPoint([epoch, value], true);
 });
 $('#resetChart').click(function() {
   var chart = $('#chart2').highcharts();
   chart.series[0].setData(null, true);
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lz8gLw8j/7/